# How to move near Real time data from an on -premises database to an AWS RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms, amazon-kinesis

I have a database hosted in my companies local data centre (**source**) and another cloud-hosted database (AWS RDS Postgres Online data store)

The local database (on-prem) is updated on an intraday basis (every 1-2 hours), how can I ensure that I move the new data to the RDS Database as soon as changes/updates occur in the local source database (we need this updated data from source to run specific processes/business logic on the RDS database as soon as changes occur in the source databases).

Would AWS DMS or AWS Kinesis be sufficient for this use case?

Comment: AWS DMS is the best option that AWS offers, but it wouldn't be "real time". I recommend that you try it and see whether it is fast enough for your needs. Otherwise, you might need a 3rd-party tool.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Thank you, let me try DMS and see if it will be sufficient for this use case ( I am trying to avoid landing the source data first in S3 as this might  introduce another lag)

Comment: @Calvin_Klyn how did this go? Did DMS provide a workable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement native replication from Postgre, it would be the best method https://hevodata.com/learn/postgresql-streaming-replication/